# Sperner's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Well, I was reading about the Sperner's theorem where it basically starts with the idea that a set which has $n$ elements and we partition those $n$ elements into some number of subsets and if among those subsets are considered as a family of sets then among those sets in that set family no one is contained within another or more specifically none of the sets there is a subset of another jn that family ...then we consider that family of set to be a Sperner Family . So basically "if there is a collection of sets and no set is a subset of another amongst them" then that is called a Sperner Family of sets . Is this the right idea?
Now as for the theorem it says that the number of such subset that should be able to form a Sperner Family is atmost ${n}\choose{[\frac{n}{2}]}$ where $[\frac n2]$ denotes the integer less than or equal to $\frac n2$. If $S$ is the Sperner's Family of sets then $|S|\leq $${n}\choose{[\frac{n}{2}]}$ . Now I am not getting the proof about Sperner's theorem.

The proof given is as follows:
Let $s_k$ denote the number of $k$-sets in $S$. For all $0\leq k \leq n$,

$n\choose [\frac n2]$$\geq $$n\choose k$
and thus $\frac{s_k}{n\choose [\frac n2]}$$\leq$$\frac{s_k}{n\choose k}$.

Since $S$ is a Sperner's family so, we can sum over and above ghe inequality
$0\leq k \leq n$ and then apply the LYM inequality to obtain

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{s_k}{n\choose [\frac n2]}$$\leq$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{s_k}{n\choose k}$$\leq$$1$

which means

$|S|=\sum_{k=0}^{n}s_k\leq $$n\choose [\frac n2]$

This completes the proof .

The LYM inequality mentioned above is used to prove the Sperner's theorem.The LYM inequality states that :

Let $U$ be an $n$ element set and let $A$ be the family of subsets of $U$ such that no set in $A$ is another set in $A$ and let $a_k$ denote the number of sets of size $k$ in $A$. Then,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac { a_k}{n\choose k}\leq 1$$

However, I did not get this part that "$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{s_k}{n\choose [\frac n2]}$$\leq$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{s_k}{n\choose k}$$\leq$$1$ " ... i mean i know they are applying LYM inequality but shouldn't

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac { a_k}{n\choose k}$$=n+1$ as $\frac { a_k}{n\choose k}=1$ as $a_k$ is number of sets of $k$ elements and $n\choose k$ denotes the same thing as $a_k$ so $n\choose k$$=a_k$...how can then this be possible? I am not getting the idea behind it....

Comment: LYM = [Lubell-Yamamoto-Meshalkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot! But can you please post the proof of LYM theorem as it requires some double counting but I am not getting it...but i also want to know whether the idea of the Sperner Family is correct or not in the above post.....